# Can I use proportion data and continous data for estimate of Spearman' s rho ? what if monotonic relatioship does not come out for a dataset ?

Tags: ordinal-data, spearman-rho, ranks

I want to use  Spearman's rho test on proportional data for one variable and continuous data for the second variable (e.g. % survival of fish related to concentration of arsenic)? Further I want to know that "Does it violate an assumption  of the Spearman's rho test to use on data that when plotted have no  monotonic relationship?"

Comment: When you say "have no monotonic relationship" do you mean you can't discern any relationship, or you *can* but it's clearly not monotonic.

Comment: Say rather than Spearman's rank correlation _quantifies_ how far you have a monotonic relationship. If it were an assumption behind the method that relationships are monotonic, then any failure to get 1 or $-$1 would be regarded as a failure of the method, but not so. The ranks don't know where they came from: the ranks for proportions would be just the same as for absolute amounts before you divide by a total.

Comment: @statsnorth your 2nd variable is well defined.The definition of Ist variable may facilitate the response from the community.

Comment: thank-you. the relationship appears visually on a plot as a straight vertical line because the % survival data is mostly 100% and then the concentration varies small changes in water quality concentration (eg ug/L of antimony), so the data appears as a  vertical line. That seems like a non-monotonic relationship that would violate the assumption of running the Spearman test.